# How to pass a function typesafe in julia

Tags: functional-programming, julia, typesafe

Let's say, I want to pass a function to another function:

```
function foo()
    return 0;
end
function bar(func)
    return func();
end
print(bar(foo));
```

But you can make functions typesafe:

```
function func(t::Int)
    print(t);
end
func(0);                 #produces no error
func("Hello world");     #produces an error
```

I didn't found out, how I combine both, that means, how can I explicitly define a parameter of `bar`, like `func`, to be a function, possibly with certain input / output argument types.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Last time I checked, those wasn't possible in Julia, but it's been a couple years so it might be now.

Comment: Thanks @setholopolus for the info. I will wait for other answers.

Comment: It's been three years, and there's still no way of specifying the type of a function/method in Julia. I've been searching for a reason for this, but couldn't find anything satisfactory...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function is of type `Function`. You can easily check this:

```
julia> foo() = 1;

julia> T = typeof(foo)
typeof(foo)

julia> supertype(T)
Function

julia> foo isa Function
true
```

This will not necessarily cover all callable types, as you can make any type callable:

```
julia> struct Callable end

julia> (::Callable)(x::Number) = x + one(x)

julia> callable = Callable()
Callable()

julia> callable(5)
6

julia> callable isa Function
false
```

Comment: Ya, but...can you specify the argument and return types of the function?

Comment: Thanks so silly. I'm sorry for not trying that before.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand you correctly you want to make sure the passed function returns a specific type? The simplest thing is to just typeassert the return value at runtime:

```
julia> function f(func)
           val = func()::Int # Error if the return value is not of type Int
           return val
       end
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f(() -> 1)
1

julia> f(() -> 1.0)
ERROR: TypeError: in typeassert, expected Int64, got Float64
Stacktrace:
 [1] f(::var"#7#8") at ./REPL[5]:2
 [2] top-level scope at REPL[8]:1
```

Alternatively you can use the [FunctionWrappers.jl](https://github.com/yuyichao/FunctionWrappers.jl) package (which will convert to the specified return type, or error if the conversion is not possible):

```
julia> using FunctionWrappers: FunctionWrapper

julia> function f(func::FunctionWrapper{Int,<:Tuple})
           val = func()
           return val
       end;

julia> function f(func)
           fw = FunctionWrapper{Int,Tuple{}}(func)
           return f(fw)
       end;

julia> f(() -> 1)
1

julia> f(() -> 1.0) # Can convert to Int
1

julia> f(() -> 1.2) # Can not convert to Int
ERROR: InexactError: Int64(1.2)
```

Comment: So there is no way built into the language to specify the argument and return types of the function being passed?

Comment: Well I see two points. When you define a function, that applies an array n times to that function, and the array is empty, then, when the function gives back another type, than it takes, there will be no error, but there should be.

Also, the definition of a function should always be near the function, not in every application of the function.

Thanks however, for the code provided. Haha I want to accept you both.